# TinyMCE - editor changing pasted content

Tags: tinymce

Two questions and maybe they are caused by the same thing/setting.

Using TinyMCE with full corporate account.  Many of the publishers are just pasting HTML into the HTML Source Editor... we are just getting this going the results are very mixed.

So if someone has a well coded page it works well - as far as we think.

But if you create a page with a couple of (or one) open div tag.  Holy cow!  The editor can throw divs everywhere - 30 extra on one page someone sent me.  Why is the editor changing content?  Can we keep this from happening?  If a publisher makes an HTML mistake we would rather that the mistake shows - not be scrubbed.

Also I noticed myself when creating menus that if you put in anything inside a link tag (like a div, ul, li, dd, dt, dl, h1-6... pretty much any tag) other than a span, that the editor will either push the tag content outside of the link tag or it will change the tag to a span.

Comment: We also noticed a similar issues with the "ul" tag.  Coded wrongly led to "ul"s all over the page.  This editor really seems like it is trying to help too much.

Comment: Why not just use a normal textarea if they are pasting in HTML content? Save yourself the trouble.

Comment: Other than that, try this: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:cleanup

Comment: The workflow is that a publisher will probably paste in HTML to start a page off.  Then a group will take over the page to do edits.  The groups really need the editor.  Also some publishers do use the editor to build their pages (very slowly) if they don't have HTML experience.  So there is no setting to keep the HTML Source from being altered.  Just seems dumb.

Comment: Did you see my second comment? That should prevent it from "fixing" things

Comment: We are using version 3.5.6 and it says that ended with 3.4.  Not sure it will work.  You know of the similar attribute for the newest version.  Sorry to be such a dumb*ss on this but I don't have direct access to the TinyMCE plugin and I am blindly helping our CMS dev guys (and don't ask me why they can't figure this out because I change my settings in WP all the time).

Comment: Apologies for not seeing it was deprecated - this one looks to still be in the current release: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:verify_html

Comment: Appreciate this was asked a while ago but does anyone know what the equivalent fix is in version 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:Cleanup/Output

Looks like the verify html is the new setting.  Will report back after testing.

David - I would have marked yours as right if you answered.  Looks like that works for 3.4 and below.

Comment: This link does not work anymore, now there's a whole Cleanup/Output section here (for TinyMCE 4.x): http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration

Comment: The link in the previous comment is also broken

Answer (score 0):

For version 3, use

```
verify_html : false
```

From here http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:verify_html